# Font size Min Max Browser support

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-size

I'm using the following CSS line of code to control the minimum and maximum `font-size` of a title:

```
font-size: min(max(35px, 4vw), 65px);
```

The minimum is 35px, maximum 65px and the fluid part is 4vw. I would like to use it in the website I'm building but I'm not sure about the browsers support. Which are the browsers supporting it? And if there are any better cross-browser solutions?

Usually when I build a website, to control the font-size I use for example `4vw` with a fallback in `em` or `px`. But the way that scales the font size is too extreme.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-math-functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max

Comment: Thank you Vishal, I will look into it!